# How to include resources from src/main/java

Tags: java, maven

I have a project that has resources inside the same package as some java classes.

The project structure is something like:

```
src
    main
        java
            nl
                project
                    someTitle.java
                    someTitle.css
```

In my pom.xml I have included the following snippet:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
             <exclude>**/*.class</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

When I do a [mvn clean verify] the .css-file does not get included in my war package. How come?

Comment: use `src/main/resources` for that. It will be autoincluded from there. Maven filters `src/main/java` for non-java files.

Comment: You should not have any resources under `/src/main/java`. Resources should be under `/src/main/resources`

Comment: I know this would be best practice, but due to legacy code I have to put it in the same package as the class...

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but... It is also weird to have class files in your source directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put files in the same package as the class, and still put the files in `src/main/resources` as suggested. Same package does not necessarily mean same *directory*.

So:

```
src
    main
        resources
            nl
                project
                    someTitle.css
```

The default Maven lifecycle will take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in resources section:

```
 <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory> 
            <includes>
                 <include>**/*.css</include> 
            </includes>
        </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: You should add some text around your answer to explain the code.